# Url Redirect using Regex only if no path in url

Tags: iis, web-config

I want to write a url redirect rule inside my Web.Config such that redirect will happen only if there is no path in the url i.e.
if my url is https://www.webpagetest.org/forums/ then it should not redirect. But if it's only https://www.webpagetest.org, redirect should happen to google.com.
Web Server is IIS

Answer (score 0):

This would check only the domain name -

```
<rule name="Rule1">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.yourdomain\.com$" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: But this doesn't redirect when I use www.yourdomain.com. I need to redirect when I use www.yourdomain.com, but not to be redirected when I use www.yourdomain.com/somepath